# Normalize string to make it file/path safe

Tags: files, string, url

Often I find my self doing this

`C-x C-f` to create a file, while in the mini buffer prompt,
paste a url like "https://github.com/seamusabshere/cache_method/issues/15" from the clipboard.

Since "https://github.com/seamusabshere/cache_method/issues/15" is not a "safe" file name, I end up manually fixing it to look like

```
https___github.com_seamusabshere_cache_method_issues_15
```

Can a pre-existing emacs function help me with this? I feel like converting a string to a filepath safe string is a common scenario in emacsland.

What I tried:
Looked in M-x list for words like "normalize" "sanitize"

Another scenario: I'm in M-x shell,
I have typed git checkout -b
and have a jira ticket url in the clipboard. I want to create branch named after the jira ticket url.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have copied the link or address you want to process.

After you have created a similar command:

```
(defun normalize-string-to-make-it-file/path-safe ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-new
   (mapconcat
    (function concat)
    (split-string
     (read-string "Input: ")
     "[:/]")
    "_")))
```

You can use "normalize-string-to-make-it-file/path-safe" to copy the converted result to the clipboard and paste it to use it.

In fact, I often use the corresponding conversion process, such as the name of the command, is also obtained in a similar way: replace the space in the title of your question with a minus sign.

Comment: didn't work for me, maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: Works for me. What exactly did you try? I did `M-x normalize-string-to-make-it-file/path-safe` then pasted `https://github.com/seamusabshere/cache_method/issues/15` at the prompt. That put the resulting string in the `kill-ring` so I could yank it (with `C-y`): `https___github.com_seamusabshere_cache_method_issues_15`. Isn't that what you asked for?